# textfile delimited java nosuchelement exception

Tags: java

I have a textfile with delimiter as shown below. I am trying to retrieve the element 1 by 1.

> 01/06/13:4pm
>
> 3:2
>
> 6:3

I am getting an no such element exception from the program when the code below is activated.

> ```
>   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("BookingMade.txt"));     
>
>  if (br.readLine() != null) {
>
>  Scanner s = new Scanner(br).useDelimiter(":");
>  System.out.println(s.next());
>  System.out.println(s.next());
>  System.out.println(s.next());
>  System.out.println(s.next());
>  System.out.println(s.next());
>  System.out.println(s.next());
>  }
>   br.close();
> ```

the output becomes

> 0
>
> 3
>
> 2
>
> 6
>
> 3

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Hi. Im trying to find out why im getting the exception error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is unclear but here is an issue: On this line you are skipping the first line of the file:

```
if (br.readLine() != null) {
```

After this there are only 4 tokens available, but you are attempting to read 6 hence the `NoSuchElementException` is thrown.

You could check for available tokens using `hasNext`:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("BookingMade.txt")).useDelimiter(":");
while (s.hasNext()) {
   System.out.println(s.next());
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. i had written a much clearer version question but the could not post and i rewrote it.

Comment: Hi, for the br.readline, im trying to check if the file is not empty. i am trying to retrieve the element 1 by 1 as i am trying to print some sentence together with the elements. which is why i did not use a while loop.

Comment: Sorry i didn't know that my br.readline is skipping the 1st line. Do you have any solution for checking if the textfile is not empty as i search a long time but i could only find solution for checking empty textfile.

Comment: You don't need to use BufferedReader at all. Scanner has the hasNext method to check if there is content available. if you don't want to use a while look then you can abstract off this functionality to a separate method, e.g. `getNextAvailableToken`

Comment: Thanks alot. i finally managed to see the date and time. can i ask, is the getnextavailabletoken in the scanner class? i cant seem to find it in the api.

Comment: No that was merely a suggestion for a helper method to eliminate multiple `hasNext` calls :)

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the error because the delimiter is no longer found while parsing BookingMade.txt.

**NoSuchElementException**

> Thrown by the nextElement method of an Enumeration to indicate that there are no more elements in the enumeration.

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot. the image helps alot in my understanding of my mistake.